# It is possible to auto send SMS for Android

Tags: android

I am not sure if this question appropriate as I new to Android. I am thinking to solve a problem such that when I am driving I want my Android to Auto send or Auto reply any incoming SMS. Would appreciate if you can guide me or provide me some tutorial or code on this. Can this task be accomplished in Android? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) (GCM) service, and each time you get an incoming message get a reply from the server. Each time you get a reply from the GCM server with the broadcastevevent you could send a auto reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for sending message, but for this first you need to set permission in android menifest file

```
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,, smsText, null, null);
```

See this tutorial for incoming messages or calls: [Android BroadcastReceiver Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. Do you mean using SmsManager to send WITHOUT user interaction like clicking a button to send? This will send DIRECTLY? But how to intercept the incoming Mobile phone number ad pass it to SMSManager? Thanks

Comment: yes, broadcast is just like a service and it have a method onReceive(), you need to override it. it will execute automatically when you receive a call or message. Write smsmanager lines in onReceive() method and you have done.  Now sms will send back automatically.

Comment: Just need to be sure. phoneNumber in this smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,, smsText, null,null) will auto insert by broacast's onreceive()? Is this the way to retrieve sender's mobile phone nbr ? Thanks

Comment: no, broadcast just provide the phone number use this method to retrive number.
message.getOrientationsAddress();

you need to store it in phoneNumber variable of type String.
[See this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)  every thing clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try Android Accessibility Service.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html

With the accessibility service in android you can get the current screen and can make the system to click buttons or send SMS automatically for you.

It can get the current screen and click into SMS, get the text box and set text, and click the send button at the end.

2. There is a useful repo is found is

https://github.com/PrivacyStreams/PrivacyStreams

You can add this build.gradle into your project and get the text box with just a few lines.

Comment: Hi do u have any example for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    int hasSMSPermission = checkSelfPermission(SEND_SMS);
                    if (hasSMSPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SEND_SMS)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Send SMS",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[] {SEND_SMS},
                                                        REQUEST_SMS);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                        requestPermissions(new String[] {SEND_SMS},
                                REQUEST_SMS);
                        return;
                    }
                    sendMySMS();
                }
            }
        });

sendButton.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    int hasSMSPermission = checkSelfPermission(SEND_SMS);
                    if (hasSMSPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SEND_SMS)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Send SMS",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[] {SEND_SMS},
                                                        REQUEST_SMS);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                        requestPermissions(new String[] {SEND_SMS},
                                REQUEST_SMS);
                        return;
                    }
                    sendMySMS();
                }
            }
        });

sendButton.performClick();
```

Source: https://github.com/delaroy/SendSms/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/delaroystudios/sendsms/MainActivity.java

just add "sendButton.performClick()" after the listener.  I tried it.